# Double api request while typing on Chrome, Only in Case of '/ping'

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

Thi is happening when I am running my node server on localhost and I go to the chrome browser and begin to type the api that I want to hit.
The sequence of events that happens is in the images [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2bNi.jpg).
This is what happens on each image:

1. I open the Google Chrome browser
2. I begin typing out the url `/ping` and it is autofilled by chrome
3. Now, although **I have not pressed enter** the api has been called according to my node server.
4. When I actually press enter the chrome browser shows the client side response.
5. There is another api call on server side now.

The issue with point 3 is not replicated with any other url that I tested.
It occurs only with `/ping`

Comment: Chrome pings some pages they know exist (e.g. been in your history) to get the title of the webpage and some information about it to give to you in the omnibar

Comment: @Quill this happens only in the case of '/ping' and i have not even pressed enter, i tried other url such as '/blog/writePost' but it did not happen then.

Comment: Yeah, chrome is a bit weird with how it works... try using a different browser and see it happens again